# Flash Builder 4 Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm having a strange issue with Flash Builder 4.
It shows all my objects in a Flash Professional FLA file as errors.

Let's say I have five buttons in my moview named: button1, button2, button3, button4, button5.
Flash Builder is flagging all of them with red error on the right side of the screen as button1 is undefined. But it is button in the FLA movie and FB4 cannot see it.

It's really annoying with a large project showing 100 errors.
This never happened before in using Flash Builder.

It still compiles and plays in Flash when I test movie, but I would like it to either see the buttons and accept them or ignore them altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with lib - playerglobal.swc
Try to remove it from library list then add it again. Path to the swc may look like this:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP10.2

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose "Flash Professional Project" when you created the Flash Builder project?

If so, check that the .fla is present and pointing to the correct path in `Project -> Properties -> Flash Professional`

and that it is set as default in `Project -> Properties -> Actionscript Applications`